# SQL Server 2005 and iTunes Library

Tags: sql-server, itunes

what's the easiest way to bulk load my iTunes library xml into an existing SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcp with xml flag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

It really depends how you want it in there and what you're purposes are, which you haven't explained.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the iTunes COM interface. There is an C# SDK that is straightforward to use and the documentation is good. You can download it here: [SDK](http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html)